# I don’t have an origin remote in my .git/config. How can I fix that?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-config

Not sure what I did wrong, but I started with a local repository, then pushed it to remote. (Yes, I am new.) My `.git/config` shows:

```
[remote "devgit"]
  url = devgit:groupname/product
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/devgit/*
```

I really expected that except in the `url` entry, that `"devgit"` should be `"origin"`. I have another repo where that is the case.

Can I change this to origin? If so, how? I want people to be able to push/pull from this repo consistently with the way they do others. What is the likely error I made setting up the remote? (I assume that is when it went awry.)

Also, this `.git/config` does not yet have a `[branch "master"]` section. Exactly what will cause that to take place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing doesn't set up a remote called `origin`; only cloning does.

You can fix this by running `git remote add origin <URL of remote repo>`, or by renaming `devgit` with `git remote rename devgit origin`.